# Is it faster to get a property or to pass a value to a method

Tags: c#, performance

I have a static class with properties to store user's inputs:

```
public static class UserData
{
    public static double UserInput1 { get; set; }
}
```

And I have nested methods that need the user's inputs

```
public static double Foo()
{
    [...]
    var input1 = UserData.UserInput1;
    var bar = Bar();
    [...]
}

private static double Bar()
{
    var input1 = UserData.UserInput1;
    [...]
}
```

The positive thing is that I do not have to pass all user inputs to `Foo()`, then to `Bar()` (and to further nested methods within `Bar()`).
The negative thing is that I have to `get` `UserData.UserInput1` and other user inputs very often. I could change the code to `get` the user inputs only once:

```
public static double Foo()
{
    [...]
    var input1 = UserData.UserInput1;
    var bar = Bar(input1);
    [...]
}

private static double Bar(double input1)
{
    [...]
}
```

Which one is faster?

Comment: And you tried measuring to see which one is faster?

Comment: [Race your own horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), and more practically, the speed difference almost certainly does not matter.

Comment: It doesn't matter ... what does matter is if the real `Bar` name is `TransformDoubleAndReturn` or `GetGlobalStateAndTransformAndReturn` and how you can test it

Comment: You are trying to optimize the wrong things. If you have a performance issue, look somewhere else. If you don't have one, focus on writing clean and readable code.

Comment: @Sweeper posting [the rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) as a comment in performance-related questions is a condescending way of saying "We won't help you. We don't share knowledge here. Answer your questions yourself."

Comment: @Sean I did not try it myself, because the real code has more nested methods and more user inputs. Before modifying the code, I wanted to check if it is worth the effort. According to Tim Schmelter it is not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Btw, I do not have a performance _issue_ but `Foo()` is in a `for` loop running 500 times. `Foo()` itself contains complex iterations. Summed up, all calculations take about 2 seconds. If I could save only 1ms in `Foo()` the total save is 0.5s = 25%.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is the faster than the first one. Because you avoid to obtain the static property from UserData.

It's not a big goal works with static when we talk about performance cost due to the need to perform a lookup in the symbol table and track shared memory. By passing input values as parameters, this is avoided and slightly better performance is achieved.

But both options are ok. It's more important to focus on code readability and maintainability rather than performance unless you are working on a critical performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one is faster?

Using static mutable state in this way will be way slower in the long run. Because you will spend a bunch of time trying to find and fix bugs. This time could be better spent doing things that will *actually* help performance, like profiling and optimizing code.

Try to make method that compute anything take the required input as parameters. Try to make input fields properties of the associated UI class. This should help keep the code simple and understandable.

Accessing a static property will be translated to a indirect memory access. Passing a parameter to a method might be free if the parameter is already in a register, or might involve a bit more work if it needs to be loaded, moved or passed on the stack. But we are talking about single digit cycles here, optimization on this level should only be done in super tight loops that are run many millions of times each second, and then you should typically ensure that all methods can be inlined, side stepping the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about such micro-optimizations (which you generally wouldn't need), consider using inlining.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions?view=net-7.0

PS: using one over the other, or using AggressiveInlining, will not save you anywhere close to the 1ms you are hoping for, under non-extreme/farfetched scenarios.